# Difficulty in calculation of gradient in this specific case

Tags: matrices

I have tried but I am not able to calculate the gradient $\bigtriangledown_{\theta}J(\theta)$ of a function $J(\theta)$.

$J(\theta) = (\| \sum_i \sum_j G_{i,j}G_{i,j}^T \|^2_{F})^{-1}$

Here $ G_{i,j} = G_{i,j}(\theta)$ is a vector function of dimension d parameterized by $\theta$.

Let $g(.)$ be the derivative of $G(.)$

Note that $G_{i,j}G_{i,j}^T$ is a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Georg, your result is exotic. I keep your definition of $A$. The OP asks for a gradient ; then I assume that $\theta=(\theta_i)_{i\leq n}$ and $J:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Thus $\nabla_{\theta}J=(\dfrac{∂J}{∂θ_i})_i$ is a vector ; unfortunately $\dfrac{∂A}{∂θ}$ is not a vector.

In fact, the correct result is $\dfrac{∂J}{∂θ_i}=\dfrac{-2}{||A||^4}trace(A^T\dfrac{∂A}{∂θ_i})$.

EDIT: Proof: Let $f(\theta)=||A||^2=trace(AA^T)$; then $J(\theta)=1/f(\theta)$ and $\dfrac{∂J}{∂θ_i}=-\dfrac{∂f}{∂θ_i}/f^2=-\dfrac{∂f}{∂θ_i}/||A||^4$. Moreover $\dfrac{∂f}{∂θ_i}=trace(\dfrac{∂A}{∂θ_i}A^T+A\dfrac{∂A}{∂θ_i}^T)=2trace(A\dfrac{∂A}{∂θ_i})\in\mathbb{R}$ (because $A$ is symmetric).

We can simplify $f(\theta)=trace(A^2)=trace(\sum_{i,j}G_{i,j}G_{i,j}^T\sum_{k,l}G_{k,l}G_{k,l}^T)=\sum_{i,j,k,l}trace(G_{i,j}G_{i,j}^TG_{k,l}G_{k,l}^T)=\sum_{i,j,k,l}trace(G_{k,l}^TG_{i,j}G_{i,j}^TG_{k,l})=\sum_{i,j,k,l}(G_{k,l}^TG_{i,j})^2$. Therefore $\dfrac{∂f}{∂θ_i}=2\sum_{i,j,k,l}G_{k,l}^TG_{i,j}(\dfrac{∂G_{k,l}^T}{∂θ_i}G_{i,j}+G_{k,l}^T\dfrac{∂G_{i,j}}{∂θ_i})$.

Comment: Please give me the source or modifiy the answer as to which result you used or how to get $trace(A^T \frac{\delta A}{\delta \theta_i})$ <br> Also is $\frac{\delta A}{\delta \theta}$ a 3 dimensional matrix as A is a matrix? ofcourse $\frac{\delta A}{\delta \theta_i}$ should be a matrix(I guess).

Comment: Also please use the fact that $g(.)$ is the derivative function of $G(.)$.

Comment: Any reference where I can learn this type of things with examples(this is a bit different from what I am used to)? And stuff like introducing trace or when I need to differentiate wrt $\theta_i$ and when can i do directly wrt the whole theta vector? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply the chain rule, the outer derivative has to be calculated:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a_{uv}}\|A\| = \frac{1}{\|A\|}a_{uv}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a_{uv}}\|A\|^{-2}=-2\,\|A\|^{-3}\frac{1}{\|A\|} a_{uv}=\frac{-2}{\|A\|^4}a_{uv}$$
where I assumed the Frobenius norm and $a_{uv}$ is an element of the real valued matrix $A$.
The matrix A given by
$$A=\sum_i \sum_j G_{i,j}G_{i,j}^T \hspace{2em} a_{uv}=\sum_i\sum_j G_{ij;u}G_{ij;v}$$
needs to be derived with respect to $\theta$:
$$\frac{\partial a_{uv}}{\partial \theta}=
\sum_i\sum_j \left( \frac{\partial G_{ij;u}}{\partial{\theta}}G_{ij;v} + 
G_{ij;u}\frac{\partial G_{ij;v}}{\partial{\theta}} \right)$$
I assume that there is really only one parameter $\theta$. In order to get the gradient (which is in the setting of just one parameter the plain derivative) one has to use the chain rule again:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\|A\|^{-2} =
\frac{-2}{\|A\|^4} \sum_{u} \sum_{v} \frac{\partial a_{uv}}{\partial \theta}$$

*EDIT:* Of course loup blanc is right and my first answer can't be valid. I tried to repair my answer. Still, loup blanc's answer looks nicer and is more general.

Comment: The main problem for me was finding $\bigtriangledown_{\theta}(G_{ij}G_{ij}^T)$ as I know g(.). One more step of chain rule. As $(G_{ij}G_{ij}^T)$ is a matrix I am not able to go one more step of chain rule.

Comment: Any reference where I can learn this type of things with examples(this is a bit different from what I am used to)? And stuff like introducing trace or when I need to differentiate wrt $\theta_i$ and when can i do directly wrt the whole theta vector? Thanks.